# Spring kafka: how to configure a serializer in a producer factory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Suppose I have this kind of [producer customizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer.html):

```
@Bean
public DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer defaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer(
    ObjectMapper objectMapper, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
  return producerFactory -> {
    final Serializer<?> valueSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>(objectMapper);
    valueSerializer.configure(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties(), false);
    producerFactory.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
  };
}
```

This code is actually not compiled:

```
java: incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<capture#2 of ?>
```

Same if I use `Serializer<Object>` instead of `Serializer<?>`, or any other type.

This can be worked if you instantiate a serializer in place, but in this case you cannot call any of its methods first:

```
producerFactory.setValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<>(objectMapper));
```

Finally, it works if you use raw types, but then a lot of warnings about it are generated.

Is there any way to make it compile without warnings and, at the same time, to have the opportunity to tune a serializer before setting it to producerFactory?

All of these statements can be applied to a [consumer customizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer.html) as well.

Comment: Error is suggesting you change `Serializer<?>` to `JsonSerializer` otherwise you can make the compiler ignore raw types

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the reply, in this case, I'll get the `Raw use of parameterized class 'JsonSerializer'` warning. So I'll need to add `@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})`. Is it the best we can do with this?

Comment: I wouldn't say "best", but if it works, it works

Comment: Ideally, you'd be consuming a specific class, which you'd put there, but if you have multiple JSON types that have no common fields or common parent class, then raw types are the best you can work with

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually you cannot put anything there if I understand it correctly. The lambda param is of type `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?>`. I tried to use `Serializer<?>`,`Serializer<Object>`,`Serializer<MyCustomDto>` etc. - neither is worked. My guess is this API simply isn't correct but probably I'm missing something.

Comment: You cannot cast? `return (DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<KClass, VClass>) producerFactory -> {`

Comment: Is it even possible in Java to cast lambda parameters? I think, this can be done only with anonymous classes. Nevertheless, the cast happens outside the scope, and we are getting an error inside of it.

Comment: Or if you meant `return (DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<KClass, VClass> producerFactory) -> {` - this doesn't work either

Comment: Hmm. Not really sure, then, outside of `return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer { @Override public void customize() { }}`